# Problems creating timer in android

Tags: android, multithreading, timer, textview

I am trying to build a timer that counts down in seconds and updates a TextView every time so it shows the time remaining. From what I can tell the timer code is working fine (1 second between events and converts from hrs and mins to secs fine) cause I have tested it outside of Android and using Log.d() in android. Updating the textview is whats giving me problems. I was getting null pointers when originally trying to update the textview cause only the UI thread can access the UI(my interpretation of the error message) and I added the runOnUiThread() which allows it to be accessed and updated but it now doesn't update correctly. I think this is where the problem lies but I am not totally sure and don't know enough to figure out how to fix it or come up with a better way to do this. I would appreciate another set of eyes. Thanks

```
final static int delay = 1000;
final static int period = 1000;


public void start(int hin, int min) {
        run = true;
        int hrinsec = (hin * (60 * 60));
        int mininsec = (min * 60);
        secs = hrinsec + mininsec;
        run = false;
        interval = secs;
        Timer t = new Timer();
        t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                // Convert seconds back to hrs and mins
                hrsFromSecs(secs);
                minsFromSecs(secs);
                secsFromSecs(secs);
                dint total = hours + minutes + seconds;
                output = hours + " Hours " + minutes + " Minutes " + seconds
                        + " Seconds";
//               Countdown and update the textview
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        timer.setText(output);
                }});

                    secs = secs - 1;
                    checkIfDone(total);
            }
        }, delay, period);
    }
```

Comment: You should use an AsyncTask for timing task. Don't run in the UI thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [CountDownTimer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html) no need to reinvent anything